# what is "?????" is in windowClosing(WindowEvent e)?

Tags: java, swing

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
{
    if(e.getSource() == getFrame().?????)
    {
        //System.exit(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        // do something another;
    }
}
```

what I want to ask is what the "?????" is?get windows' what?

Comment: It would really help if you'd say where you came across this to start with...

Comment: That is not valid in Java. Where did you find this?

Comment: @Thomas, he wants to know what method or field to use at the place marked with `?????`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code is trying to check if the source of a windows closing event is the "main" `Frame` of the application, and if so, to `System.exit(0)` (which is currently commented out).

There's [`java.awt.Frame.getFrames()`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Frame.html#getFrames%28%29) which returns an array of all `Frame` created by this application. There's also [`com.javaranch.common.AWT.getFrame(Component c)`](http://www.javaranch.com/doc/com/javaranch/common/AWT.html#getFrame%28java.awt.Component%29) which is obviously a non-standard library method.

In any case, it's not clear that `getFrame()`-etc is necessary at all. Depending on the context where this method appears, the right hand side may simply be `this`, or perhaps `Frame.this`. This latter syntax is called the "qualified `this`" expression, which can be used from within an inner class (commonly used as event listeners) to refer to the `this` instance of an enclosing class.